# %{REQUEST_URI} doesn't seem to work with index.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that uses the following format of links:

```
http://www.website.com/section1/index.php
http://www.website.com/section2/index.php
http://www.website.com/section3/index.php
http://www.website.com/section1/section4/index.php
```

What I was trying to do is to get rid of the last part "index.php" by using the following .htaccess directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.google.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Of course, www.google.com is just for testing purposes, however the example below doesn't work. What is wrong with it? The second part of the question is what do I replace www.google.com with if I want to rewrite to http://www.website.com/section1 ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because your regex is incorrect. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$` is expecting `%{REQUEST_URI}` to be `/index.php` but you have `/section1/index.php`.

Correct version will be:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Or even:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /index\.php$ http://www.google.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Would this be the best solutions? RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: One more question. This solutions seems to add a trailing slash to the end of the url... :/ this is my .htaccess: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: Is it adding trailing slash on all the URLs or just to the URLs that resolve to a real directory?

Comment: On all. Take a look here: http://www.ocdexperience.com/home-organization/household-management/

Comment: It doesn't add slash when 404 happens e.g. http://www.ocdexperience.com/home. Is it some CMS framework that you're using? I don't see any rule here that is trailing slash.

Comment: No framework. Maybe some kind of server configuration?

Comment: Since your web server is `nginx` I believe there is some configuration or server side rule doing this 301. You're sure `home-organization/household-management` is not a directory right?

Comment: Yes, it is a directory.

Comment: If that is a directory then it is normal for web servers to add a trailing slash. Turning it off is considered a security risk.